# Android animation in a recycler view to change bounds?

Tags: java, android

I have a recycler view and the rows in each recycler view can have varying size depending on information inside them which is dynamically filled into it.

Now when I scroll the recycler view the layout gets inflated and there is a sudden jerk in the screen. So i want to animate this part where i can just expand the lower bound of the row or any other method suitable. 
How do i animate just the lower bound?? please help..

i have used this code

```
int height = holder.customLayout.getHeight();
holder.customLayout.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(1000);
```

but it messes up with entire view

Comment: How do you set your `height` of your `customLayout`? Do you use `wrap_content`?

Comment: yes i use wrap content... later inflate inner view and add to customlayout

Comment: Could you please add screenshots what exactly is messed up? It may be that you get the wrong `height` because it is not calculated correctly.

Comment: using this code actually moves the entire view to new position so it messes up